# How to solve a linear programming question with an "average" constraint

Tags: linear-programming

I'm trying to solve the question below:

"An $8$ year old child usually has $24$ teeth. A dental researcher has estimated that on an average, $8$ year old kids in a geographical region have $1.8$ decayed teeth each. Give LP formulations for the problems of finding the minimum and maximum possible values for the fraction
of $8$ year old kids in that region who have $2$ or more decayed teeth."

I know that finding the min would just be $-$(max), so that's not a problem, but I'm stuck on how to use the "$1.8$ decayed teeth on average" as a constraint. The only thing I can think of is letting $x$ be the number of decayed teeth and making one of the constraints $\frac{x}{24}=1.8$, but then wouldn't that just make the objective function always give the answer that the fraction of kids with $2$+ decayed teeth be $0$??

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i$, $0 \leq i \leq 24$, be the fraction of 8 year old kids in the geographical region having $i$ decayed teeth.  Notice we have the constraint
$$  \sum_{i=0}^{24} x_i = 1  \text{.}  $$
Now to represent your constraint, temporarily let $N$ be the number of 8 year old kids in the geographical region.  For each $i$, $x_i N$ of them have $i$ decayed teeth.  So the average number of decayed teeth, $A$, is 
$$ A = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{24} i x_i N = \sum_{i=0}^{24} i x_i = 1.8  \text{,}  $$
the rightmost equality being a plain linear constraint.